# Reunite the Stars

Tags: mathematics, geometry, strategy

On an infinite plane, the Prime Star has disintegrated into four constituent stars, the North Star, the South Star, the East Star and the West Star, each traveling at a constant speed of 1 in their eponymous directions.

[image]

The Star Guardian at the center wants to reunite the four Stars back into the Prime Star again, which can only be achieved if the four Stars meet at a single point in spacetime. Furthermore:

1. The Star Guardian moves at a constant speed of $g$, in any direction she wants.
2. She is only able to take one Star with her in her movement.
3. Once left alone, the four Stars always travel in their eponymous directions at speed 1.
4. If only two or three Stars meet, they will just pass through each other without any interaction.

Suppose now 1 unit of time has passed so each Star is at distance 1 from the Guardian, what is the minimum value of $g$ for her to be able to reunite the Stars in finite time? How long will it take her in that mission?

---

Update: it is **possible** that there exists $g^*$, such that the Guardian is able to complete her mission for any $g\gt g^*$, but not for $g\leq g^*$. If this is the case, identify this $g^*$.

Comment: What's the air speed velocity of a laden Star Guardian?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Always g, laden or not.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore What do you mean? An African or European Star Guardian?

Comment: Are you sure such a minimum _g_ does actually exist? My gut feeling would be that there is some "stalemate" value and any value above it will suffice but not the stalemate value itself. In that scenario there is no smallest _g_.

Comment: I've actually calculated a stalemate value at 4.06643... but that assumes a certain geometry is optimal which I cannot prove.

Comment: @loopywalt Yes, a priori it's possible that such a minimum g doesn't exist, but I don't know for sure. In your stalemate does the Guardian try to reunite the Stars at the center point where the Prime Star used to be?

Comment: Yes, though in the limitng cycle only N/S and E/W are aligned in time. Say the guardian catches N at 1 unit out tows it over to S a bit farther out drops it while collecting S and returns to its starting point total effect being N and S exactly swapped. Then goes diagonally to E catching it also at one unit out and swaps E and W then goes diagonally back to N.

Comment: @loopywalt, in your stalemate value, then the guardian reaches the last star to be carried in the infinity?

Comment: My mathematical intuition (rather than a formal proof) suggests that for pretty much any geometry of the collecting pattern, the minimum g would be a limit as the geometry expands towards infinity - informally, if there were a hard minimum with a bounded pattern, it would imply that collecting the stars in a slightly expanded version of the pattern (with the stars having moved further and thus taking more time) would require the guardian to move faster, but with more time to collect the stars, the guardian can move a tiny bit slower and still catch each star before it reaches the boundary.

Comment: @justhalf no, its a finite cycle but no side wins. The stars do not escape to  inifinity but neither does the guardian manage to get them back (S/N and E/W will altermately meet at the centre). Now if the speed is slightly increased/decreased the pattern will geometrically shrink/expand over time. In the first case it will take infinitely many cycles but finite time to finish.

Comment: @Steve yeah that's pretty my intuition, too.

Comment: @loopywalt Why swap E and W if you can just catch W and take it all the way to the center for a reunion with the other three? Would that require less speed?

Comment: @Steve The initial distance btw the guardian and the stars (i.e. the scale) doesn't matter. A collecting pattern at scale 1 accomplishes the mission in time t if and only if the same collecting pattern at scale n accomplishes the mission in time nt.

Comment: @Eric good point. Once we are in the limiting cycle this can definitly be made to work and would indeed require less speed. I'm just not sure we can get to the limitng cycle with less speed. Whether something similar can be done in the initial configuration (where N/S and E/W are not out of phase) is certainly worth checking.

Comment: @loopywalt My feeling is that getting to a limiting cycle from the initial configuration requires less speed than reuniting the stars directly. Another point is that there are many different ways to arrive at different limiting cycles. Maybe getting to other cycles requires less speed.

Comment: Actually, it may well be that an exponentially expanding version of the limitng cycle would be sufficient because we can cut it short using your idea.

Comment: Oh, interesting, so a series of cycles will be faster than simply using one cycle (that is, each star is only carried once to their corresponding position such that they eventually meet).

Comment: @loopywalt, Retudin answer is similar to what I have in mind. Can you give some rough range of what the answer would be with the cycles to see if they are competitive?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATED WITH A COMPLETE REWRITE**

A minimum velocity does

> not exist.

First observe the hard lower bound

> g > 3

This is straightforward to establish:

> Consider the velocity vectors of the freely moving star. These are constant unit vectors representing the four principal winds. Now take scalar product of each with the corresponding star's position vector. For each star that is not in the immediate care of the guardian this product will grow at a rate of 1. Now consider the sum of these scalar products. When all stars meet its value is zero. In the initial configuration it is four, so to make the stars meet it must be shrunk. As at each time at least three stars contribute growth at rate 1 each the guardian can not compensate unless its speed is strictly above 3.

I will now show simulations of a strategy that strongly suggest that

> any *g* > 3 is actually good enough:

The strategy has to phases:

Phase 1:

> Cycle through the stars E->N->W->S->E->... always using the quickest intercept course to reach the next and always carry the just intercepted star all the way to the next (so we never travel empty).

> [image]
>  
>  This is a simulation with *g* about 1% above 3. Values much closer to 3 give qualitatively the same picture.
>  
>  Panel 1: At first the configuration appears to expand rather quickly.
>  Panel 2: But a spiralling pattern is quickly establishied with the rate of expansion shrinking over time ...
>  Panel 3: ... until it is actually reversed resulting in a collapsing spiral.
>  Panel 4: This, however, is reversed again at some point leading to renewd growth.
>  Panels 5 and 6: The trend keeps reversing resulting in perpetual oscillation.

Phase 2:

> The second part of the strategy breaks this yoyo behaviour the instant the system first goes into shrinkage by tempering its rate. More precisely, as soon as the guardians steps are detected to reduce the lateral (wrt its current cargo's free velocity vector) displacement we reduce the reduction by 50%  (smaller values resulting in faster convergence are also possible,see below for an example). In simulations this reliably prevented the next reversal.

> [image]

> [image]
>  
>  The last curve summarised the continual reduction of the configuration's diameter many orders of magnitude below its inital value in finite time.

Few more examples with

> *g* < 3.001
>  
>  [image]
>  
>  and the same with reduced shrinkage reduction (6% instead of 50%).
>  
>  [image]
>  
>  *g* < 3.0003 ; shrinkage reduction < 1%
>  
>  [image]
>  
>  *g* < 3.00003 ; shrinkage reduction < 1‰
>  
>  [image]

Comment: Can you explain how to perform the last cycle to make them converge at the same location?

Comment: Also I get it now about your strategy. Basically we consider the value $V$ to be the sum of speed of the stars moving away from our designated rendezvous point. Since we can carry 1, maximum $V$ is at least 3, so g should at least be 3 as well to "counter" this effect.

Comment: @justhalf I don't because it is not necessary. The cycle time decays exponentially; therefore the total time, i.e. the sum of cycles converges meaning after a finite time we will have performed infinitely many cycles and all stars be at zero.

Comment: Why is 3 the hard limit？

Comment: Hm, I get the math, but sounds counterintuitive lol. I guess the resolution is similar to Achilles and the tortoise.

Comment: @loopywalt, and while you're at it, can you say something as well about how even though there are three stars moving, that the hard limit is 3 even though we can make such that one of the stars we are not carrying is actually going towards the point.

Comment: For 2 points, the limiting cycle is at g=1. Can we find a limiting cycle at g=3 for 4 points?

Comment: @Eric see justhalf's comment or my comment to the deleted answer.

Comment: @justhalf If we are allowed to distribue the inital distances at will we can. The trick is to make E arrive at zero the moment we deliver S and similarly for N and W.

Comment: I see. Also, so this strategy has two phases? The first hundred cycles (as you mention) will increase the total distance, but afterward it keeps decreasing? Is this accurate? Or can you describe the behavior of the system as a whole?

Comment: @justhalf the strategy itself doesn't change; only how the system responds. It will converge only once the distances are close enough to a certain ratio, During the expanding phase the system moves towards this ratio. Why this behaviour emerges at g=10/3 I don't really know, that's why I call this answer "experimental".

Comment: Yes, I mean the behavior of the system has two phases.

Comment: If you can do it for for some initial distances, I guess $g^*=3$ for the original problem, too. The question is how to get to the desired distances. But of course it is entirely possible that for some initial distances we'll not be able to do that.

Comment: @Eric, what do you mean by original problem?

Comment: @loopywalt, do you have analytical solution for the 10/3?

Comment: I'd got some calculations in Excel towards trying out a different idea, and have modified them to confirm this cycle, and also make some further tweaks - it's possible to drop off the stars a little "early" or "late" if desired, and the pattern still converges if not too much "slack" is taken away. I strongly suspect that using this "wiggle room" would allow for finding a solution for a specific value of $g > g^*$ that is not only completed within a finite time, but also a finite number of steps, but I've not yet found a specific procedure...

Comment: @Steve cool! In case it helps: I have observed that once the simulatin is in the shrinking phase g can be switched  to 3+epsilon and it will still converge. At this point S and W will stay nonpositive all the time. Do your calculations give any clue why 10/3 should be the magic number?

Comment: If we generalize a bit and let the Prime Star break into N Sub Stars, evenly distributed on a circle and with directions of velocities fixed in the spirit of the 4 Stars case. Do you think $g^*(N)$ grows linearly?

Comment: We can also generalize to higher dimensions m, by having 2m stars evenly distributed on the unit circle centered at the origin. Do you think $g^*$ will grow linearly as dimensions increase?

Comment: @Eric yes, that is actually easy to see in both scenarios. We have the lower bound g > 2m-1 (take sum of the dot products of the stars' positions and velocity vectors with no guardian this will increase at a rate of 2m with guardian at a rate >= 2m-1 - g) for an upper bound 4m + epsilon will allow you to go for one star after the other and bring it back to the origin. over time the individual distances will equilibrate and shrink.

Comment: Another interesting twist: if you allow the four stars to start with different initial positions, or even different preferred directions (other than due East, due West etc.), will $g^*$ ever increase with respect to the $g^*$ in the original problem?

Comment: What about going in circles carrying one star after another, the guardian always being loaded. Will this scheme be better?

Comment: @Eric have you been reading my mind again? I'm in the middle of updating my answer with exactly that.

Comment: "we reduce the reduction by 50%" what do you mean by this? Surely it's not about reducing the speed of the guardian. But what?

Comment: @justhalf Begin by picturing the "square equilibrium" the guardian visits the corners ccw for eample moving the S star from the SE corner back to the NE corner where he drops it and picks up the E star etc. this is stable at g=3. if g is slightly faster the guardian could have afforded to go slightly more W instead of straight N, meeting the E star slightly earlier and reducing the S stars lateral (i.e.perpendicular to its own movement preference N->S) displacement. Now, by not going quite as far W as we could (thereby reducing the reduction) we give away a bit of the guardian's speed ...

Comment: ... but stabilise the shrinking trend. Purely empirical, I have no proof whatsoever for that.

Comment: Ah, I see, so it's more meta description on what we are doing, ok. Nice solution! So the answer is g* = 3 then, based on the last clarification in the question.

Comment: I am not convinced by the proof that g>3. Imagine a similar problem but with just 3 stars - 2 stars going East, one going West. Any speed g>1 suffices to bring those stars together, while your argument would suggest g>2 is needed.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis ah, but in your example the sum needn't go to zero for the stars to reunite; in the original  situation it clearly must (pair E/W and S/N to see).

Comment: Clearly? Well, not to me yet. If it must sum to zero, then you are using position vectors that are centred on the final meeting point. In my example that meeting point is off to the East, so that the initial sum is already negative, giving time for the guardian to set things up. It may seem obvious but I don't think your argument rigorously proves that this kind of thing won't work for four stars.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Hm, I'd normally take your doubts very seriously, but in this case I'm 99.99% sure you are just having a really bad day. The point is that the four vectors come in pairs E/W and S/N that are opposite therefore E+W+S+N = (E+W) + (S+N) = 0 + 0 = 0. Now, if the stars unite at point P then the sum <E,P> + <W,P> + <S,P> + <N,P> the scalar product being linear in either argument evaluates to <0,P> = 0

Comment: @loopywalt: Just wondering: Did you also simulate the other always-carrying option NSEW? I would not be surprised if that would converge faster (for any g>3) - but I may be terribly wrong.

Comment: @Retudin did it now.Doesn't look too promising. Mind you I didn't try too hard;  it may still be possible.

Comment: @loopywalt I got it now. I was being a bit slow, but I am now fully convinced that the proof works. I didn't realise that the fact that the four star vectors balance out means that it does not matter how the positional vectors are defined. My mental picture of what the sum of those dot products represented was off when the origin or meeting point was elsewhere. A sign error basically.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Yep, it's the same principle that lets you, for example, calculate sample covariances centring only one factor.. As soon as one factor is zero mean it kills any bias the other may still have.

Comment: Is the oscillation always there or just for g slightly larger than 3? So it seems if you have N stars whose unit velocity vectors sum to zero, then $g^*\leq N-1$. And if they don't sum to zero, then $g^*\lt N-1$. If true, I feel there must be some intuitive explanation for this. A conservation law or something.

Comment: @Eric Oscillations are also refleclted in the sum of dot product which goes negatice during contractins whiiich is only possible if _g_>3.

Comment: If g=3, will the phase I square size grow to infinity?

Comment: @Eric I think otherwise there would have to be a limiting cycle with positive sum of dot products which I can't picture,

Answer (score 6):

> I have a strategy with infimum $g^* = \frac{1}{2}\left(4+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{22+4\sqrt{2}}\right) \approx 5.336596$, and any larger value is a solution. For example, $g = 5.3366$ is doable (with the corresponding $X \approx 117058$).
>  $g* = 5.31317$ is feasable when not ending in the origin (I uses a MP solver for this)

The strategy:

> move to/ pick up weststar
>  move far to the east distance $(g+1)X$ and release west
>  move to the west, pick up eaststar on the way and drop it at $(g-1)X$ west
>  note: east and west will reach origin at the same time

> move southeast and pick up southstar
>  note: at this $g$ you will meet the star at $(g-1)X$ to the south of the origin
>  move to $(g+1)X$ north to get the north star; drop southstar at the right moment on the way (precisely at $\frac{X(g-1)(g-1-\sqrt{2})}{g+1}$, which we can confirm is less than $(g+1)X$)
>  move northstar to the origin

> note all stars reach the origin at the same time
>  weststar is dropped at $(g+1)X$ east at time $\frac{X(g+1)}{g}$
>  eaststar is dropped at $(g-1)X$ west at time $\frac{X(3g+1)}{g}$
>  southstar is picked up at $(g-1)X$ south at time $\frac{X(3g+1)}{g} + \frac{X(g-1)\sqrt{2}}{g}$
>  and this works since for $g^*$ specified above, we have: $(g-1)X = \frac{X(3g+1)}{g} + \frac{X(g-1)\sqrt{2}}{g}$
>  northstar is picked up at $(g+1)X$ north at time $(g-1)X +2X$
>  all are together at time $\frac{X(g+1)^2}{g}$
>  [image]
>  Notes:
>  This assumes there is no initial distance, but the calculation still works, i.e., the same $g^*$ would be the solution with the initial distance in (just need to add $\frac{2}{g-1}$ to the time to get to the southstar. Note that this doesn't affect the rest of the calculation due to how we pick the distances).

> The solution is not optimal; With a similar strategy, one can do slightly better while ending up south-west of the origin.
>  EDIT: The direction is an error on my part. I expected the configuration below to be more efficient. I reasoned the angle at a is sharper than at c and thus moving the end position towards c would help. (I tried it using a solver but there is only an adverse effect.)

> [image]
>  However, changing the endpoint to (1,-1) gives an improvement
>  According to my solver $g* = 5.31317$
>  For $A = 11.456, B = 3.649, C = 6.132$
>  [image]

Comment: Nice strategy! Given that you provide a number with such precision, perhaps you can try to calculate the actual value given the initial distance of the four stars?

Comment: Your total time of $X(g+1)/(g-1)$ is not correct, as it is clearly less than $X(g+1)$, the time at which North Star is picked up. It should be $X(g+1) + X(g+1)/g$ or $X(g+1)^2/g$

Comment: @justhalf $X\approx185435$

Comment: I tried calculating this to include the initial distance, and this doesn't work, as X would be negative (due to the requirement that g needs to be [large enough](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-1%29y+%3D+2%2F%28x-1%29+%2B+%283x%2B1%29y%2Fx+%2B+%28x-1%29y*sqrt%282%29%2Fx%3B+x%3D1%2F2+%283+%2B+sqrt%282%29%29+%2B+1%2F2+sqrt%2815+%2B+2+sqrt%282%29%29), to catch up to north star in time to get back to origin at the same time with other three stars)

Comment: Oh, it does work with the specified g here though. And it seems to be the infimum for this strategy.

Comment: So precisely g* (the infimum) should be $\frac{1}{2}\left(4 + \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{22+ 4 \sqrt{2}}\right)$, and the resulting formula for X for larger g [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28g-1%29X+%3D+2%2F%28g-1%29+%2B+%283g%2B1%29X%2Fg+%2B+%28g-1%29X*sqrt%282%29%2Fg%3B+g%3D1%2F2+%284+%2B+sqrt%282%29+%2B+sqrt%282+%2811+%2B+2+sqrt%282%29%29%29%29). For completeness, [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+-+%283%2Bsqrt%282%29%29x+%2B+sqrt%282%29-1+%3E%3D+0) is one minimum condition on g to be able to catch up in time.

Comment: @Retudin, I wonder, what makes you think that making them meet southwest of the origin would require less $g^*$?

Comment: @jushalf  I have a feasible plan for g<4.

Comment: You should tag the answerer, which is I am not =) I'm just completing the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. @justhalf see my additions for the 'not at origin' solution

Answer (score 0):

> $g=4$ is enough.

> First, notice that the initial distance btw the guardian and the stars (i.e. the scale) doesn't matter. A collecting pattern at scale $1$ accomplishes the mission in time $t$ **if and only if** the same collecting pattern at scale $x$ accomplishes the mission in time $xt$. With this in mind, let's start with each star at distance $1$ from the origin and the guardian at the northstar, and follow the instructions below:

1. Carry N southward. Drop N upon meeting S and carry S northward to point (0, 1). This step takes $t_0=1.33$ time. At the end the four stars are at N(0, -1), S(0, 1), W(-2.33, 0), E(2.33, 0) and the guardian is at S.
2. Drop S and head straight for the point (-1.86, 0) to meet W, which takes $t_1=0.53$ time.
3. Carry W eastward to the point (0, 3.1) to meet E, dropping W somewhere en route at point $W_d$ (to be determined). This step takes $t_2=1.24$ time.
4. Carry E westward for a time $t_3=0.96$ to the point (-0.74, 0). $W_d$ in step 3 is chosen so that at the end of $t_3$, W is at the point (0.74, 0).

> At the end of step 4, $t_1+t_2+t_3=2.73$ time has passed since S is dropped. So now the four stars are at N(0, 1.73), S(0, -1.73), E(-0.74, 0) W(0.74, 0) and the guardian is at E. **Notice this is exactly the situation at the end of step 1, only shrinked by a factor of 0.74!** By repeating the above cycle, the guardian can converge the four stars in $1.33+\frac{2.73}{1-0.74}=11.83$ units of time.

Comment: But the position of the guardian at the end of step 1 and step 4 seem to be different? Ah, noted, it's also rotated.

Comment: The final time needs to include the additional time taken to reach your starting position, and then re-scaled to the scale of the position as it stands at that point. i.e. your real final time is $(1 + 4 * 11.83)/3 \approx 16.11$

Comment: @Steve I assumed a different starting point for the guardian in the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: Indeed, reaching your assumed starting point from the actual starting point takes 1/3 time units, and scales the whole problem by a factor of 4/3

Comment: Perhaps more importantly, you have errors in steps 2 and 3. W ended step 1 at (-2.33,0), and after 0.53 time will be at (-2.86,0), so when we get to (-1.86,0) we are still 1 unit away from W. Similarly, in step 3 even if we could pick up W at that time, E will have travelled to (2.33 + 0.53 + 1.24 = 4.1), so we're also 1 unit short of picking it up at (0, 3.1). Certainly this iterative technique works, but not with the specific numbers you're citing.

Comment: @Steve Ah... you're right. That's too bad. There's no guarantee the technique works for g=4 then... probably not any more. I'll check again. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The technique seems to me broadly similar to the one in @loopywalt's answer which works for significantly lower values of g, so g=4 definitely possible with an equivalent iterative technique, although perhaps not with such an elegant pattern.

Comment: @Steve Indeed, this program no longer works. Sad.